# Safari без мака

Tags: html

Как протестировать верстку на сафари, если нету MAC. ?

Comment: А Вы что, тестируете сайт ставя на компьютер браузеры по очереди? В онлайн режиме это делайте, есть много сервисов, позволяющие протестировать сайт в разных браузерах.

Comment: Например [тут](https://www.browserling.com/) можно проверить на разных версиях 4 известых браузера.

Comment: Safari есть для винды, но он последние годы не обновляется

Comment: Хакинтош?) ещё интересна мобильная сафари

Comment: Ещё можно virtualbox с маком найти

Comment: Часто мне задавали этот вопрос поэтому написал статью https://get-web.site/blog/104-testiruem-verstku-v-safari-bez-makbuka-proverka-krossbrauzernosti-otladka-js-v-macos-iz-pod-windows.html а от скринов с онлайн сервисов толку мало

Answer (score 3):

Единственный хороший способ протестировать верстку на различных устройствах ( в том числе safari) - [browserstack.com](https://www.browserstack.com/)

Есть возможность полной эмуляции устройств, скриншоты и панель разработчика.

Правда минус - испытать все возможности ресурса можно только с платной версией!

Больше о кроссбраузерном тестировании можно [почитать на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/82473/)